# A Java date string in the format "07-apr-2016" produces wrong result when converted to sqldate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1;        
formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");
java.util.Date dt = formatter1.parse(t5.getText()); 
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cid);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,bid);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,t1.getText());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+sqlDate);
```

I get the different date when am printing sqlDate. When I give input 07-apr-2016, I get the value in sqldate as 2015-12-27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),Y means week year,y means year

change your code `formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");` to `formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is incorrect, the right one is `dd-MMM-yyyy` not `dd-MMM-YYYY`